# Join two Tables and add Count result

Tags: sql, select, join

I have 2 Tables A & B

**A**

```
select TranType, DocType, Document  FROM
db1.dbo.A

TRANTYPE | DOCTYPE  | DOCUMENT
Coup     | Stat     | 1
Coup     | Stat     | 2
Coup     | Stat     | 3
Coup     | Stat     | ...
Coup     | Stat     | 100
Swp      | Corr     | 1
Swp      | Corr     | 2
Swp      | Corr     | ...
Swp      | Corr     | 5
```

**B** ...

**A:**

```
SELECT  TranType, DocType, COUNT (*) AS Docs 
FROM db1.dbo.A 
GROUP BY TranType, DocType

TRANTYPE | DOCTYPE  | DOCS
Coup     | Stat     | 100
Swp      | Corr     | 5
```

**B:**

```
SELECT  RecType, SubType, COUNT (*) AS Docs 
FROM db2.dbo.B 
GROUP BY RecType, SubType

RECTYPE  | SUBTYPE  | DOCS
Coup     | Stat     | 50
Cr       | Cr       | 3
Swp      | Cr       | 10
```

I managed to get the intersection of the 2 Tables and Add up the Count result:

**A ∩ B**

```
SELECT a.TranType, a.DocType,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db2.dbo.B b WHERE b.RecType= a.TranType AND b.SubType = a.DocType) +
     COUNT(a.TranType) AS SUM
FROM db1.dbo.A a 
GROUP BY a.TranType, a.DocType 
ORDER BY TranType

TRANTYPE | DOCTYPE  |  SUM
Coup     | Stat     |  150
```

Anyone got an idea how to get all the entries (Union)?

```
TRANTYPE | DOCTYPE  | DOCS
Coup     | Stat     | 150    <----
Swp      | Corr     | 5
Cr       | Cr       | 3
Swp      | Cr       | 10
```

SOLUTION:
I had different collation on my tables, resulting in an error.

Find the solution with proper collation handling here: [SQL Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44b5f/7)

Comment: can you show us what the union will looks like?

Comment: please show example of what output you want -- you were so close to making a very clear question

Comment: I expect you don't want a union you want a left join (which is why web searches are not helpful).  Maybe you want a cross join.

Comment: Your first query isnt really Intersection, because you are SUM both matching result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c80d/3)**

`UNION` is easy. Just need matching column name

Or `UNION ALL` to keep duplicated

```
SELECT TranType, DocType, SUM (Docs)
FROM (
      SELECT  TranType, DocType, COUNT (*) AS Docs 
      FROM TableA
      GROUP BY TranType, DocType
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  RecType as TranType, SubType as DocType, COUNT (*) AS Docs 
      FROM TableB 
      GROUP BY RecType, SubType
     ) T
GROUP BY TranType, DocType
ORDER BY TranType, DocType;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| TranType | DocType |     |
|----------|---------|-----|
|     Coup |    Stat | 150 |
|       Cr |      Cr |   3 |
|      Swp |    Corr |   5 |
|      Swp |      Cr |  10 |
```

**EDIT**

Your first query should be write like this to avoid perfom a subquery for each row.

```
SELECT TranType, DocType, SUM (Docs)
FROM (
      SELECT  TranType, DocType, COUNT (*) AS Docs 
      FROM TableA
      GROUP BY TranType, DocType
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  RecType as TranType, SubType as DocType, COUNT (*) AS Docs 
      FROM TableB 
      GROUP BY RecType, SubType
     ) T
GROUP BY TranType, DocType
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: @Hogan Are you sure? His new output request looks like union to me

Comment: Hi I tried this out but got an error message (translated error message) :

The db1.dbo.A.DocType Column is not valid in the  shortlist, because its neither in an aggregate function or in the Group BY Clause

Comment: what is your rdbms? sql server, mysql, postgres?

Comment: I am using sql server.
In my query i also use _COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_ after the group by clause so that i don't get a sorting conflict,  maybe the error is here somewhere?

Comment: @Mance check my update, I include a sqlfiddle demo so can see it working.

Comment: Im really sorry to disturb, but actually the output in your example is not right. Your output is:
|    Coup |    Stat   |  100 |
|       Cr   |      Cr   |    3   |
|      Swp |    Corr  |    5   |
|      Swp |      Cr   |   10  |

Output should be 
|    Coup |    Stat   |  200 |
|       Cr   |      Cr   |    3   |
|      Swp |    Corr  |    5   |
|      Swp |      Cr   |   10  |

Comment: @Mance You dont need write output in comment, just edit your question and let me know by a comment. Also please dont say my output wasnt right because you just edit the question and change the output. Give me a second and I will update.

Comment: I update my answer. But now I see your sample data say `Swp, Corr has 1, 3 and 5` so there is no way output will be `5` so check again your question data and desire output.

Comment: Your answer is correct and works perfectly in the fiddle:) sorry for that! I will try to get it working at my local machine i still get the same error from above

Comment: Then update the fiddle with real data so we can see the error. Otherwise Isnt much we can do to help you if we dont have the right data.

Comment: added new fiddle, you can see that i get the error now

Comment: @Mance again you include new information on your own question not on my answer. I saw your new data, what result you expect from that?

Comment: The output Example in your answer is correct.  But if you try your query in my fiddle you can see that it won't work due to the Collation

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Next time will help if you say there is an error... and put the error message

Comment: WORKS. Thanks alot! :) P.S Error message is above in comment

Comment: Sorry accidentally double clicked the button :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using subqueries and then aggregating:

```
select TranType, DocType, sum(docs) as docs
from ((select TranType, DocType, count(*) as docs
       from db1.dbo.A a
       group by TranType, DocType
      ) union all
      (select RecType, SubType, count(*) as docs
       from db1.dbo.B
       group by RecType, SubType
      )
     ) ab
group by TranType, DocType;
```

You can also use a `full outer join`, but then you have to deal with `NULL` values in the final result.

Note:  this will return all pairs, even those in only one table.

Comment: I just cant get it work always getting the same error: The db1.dbo.A.DocType Column is not valid in the shortlist, because its neither in an aggregate function or in the Group BY Clause

Comment: @Mance . . . I don't think anything in this query could cause that error.  Can you post the link to your SQL Fiddle?  Every column in the `select` lists is appropriately also mentioned in the `group by`.

Comment: Problem was not your query but my tables collation. Thats why I had that error. If you like check fiddle out following fiddle with sample table setup http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44b5f/7. It has attached solution with right collation handling

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a cross join?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT  TranType, DocType, COUNT (*) AS ACount 
  FROM db1.dbo.A 
  GROUP BY TranType, DocType
) A, (
  SELECT  RecType, SubType, COUNT (*) AS BCount
  FROM db2.dbo.B 
  GROUP BY RecType, SubType
) B
WHERE A.DocType = B.SubType
```

Comment: Hi I tried this out but got an error message: The db1.dbo.A.DocType Column is not valid in the shortlist, because its neither in an aggregate function or in the Group BY Clause

Comment: Sounds like you have a typo and did not copy exactly what I have.  I see DocType in that group by

Comment: When i run both subselects one after another they work by alone, just the whole query wont, I double checked it, the only difference is i use _COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_ after both group by clauses. 
I updated the question could you please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

All solutions till now just overcomplicating the problem. Also do you want counts or sums?

```
SELECT TranType, DocType, SUM(DOCS) DOCS--or COUNT(DOCS) DOCS
FROM (SELECT TranType, DocType, DOCS FROM A
      UNION ALL
      SELECT RecType, SubType, DOCS FROM B) t
GROUP BY TranType, DocType
```

Comment: Hi I need both, first to count the Documents from table A and then summing that up with the count result from the second table B.